# Removing a non linear noise trend from data

Tags: probability-or-statistics, filtering

I have a dataset that looks as follows
[image]
Now, this is from an actual measurement (of the reflection coefficient of a microchip with four LC resonators connected in a periodic fashion) so there is obviously noise involved. For reference, this is what it should look like in theory (with different numerical parameters)
[image]

So there's a few things about the data. First of all there is gaussian(?) noise around the 'mean'. This is not really an issue; I'm only really interested in the positions/sharpness/depths of the resonances, and the noise doesn't complicate it too much. I suppose that if it would be very problematic, one could use GaussianFilter? But then there's a more problematic issue, and that is also why I put accents around mean. The data is not in a straight line; there is some nonlinear trend over the range of the data. This is what my question is about; getting rid of this trend so that the data is on a straight line. Once that is done, getting it to have its mean at 1 is of course easy, and I'll have a dataset that can be fitted with the model.

My issue is that I don't really know where to start. I did some searching, but either my search terms are terrible or this hasn't really been discussed; it is quite specific after all. I'd like your advice on how to proceed, as personally I don't have any clue. Maybe I should fit the data with some general function? It does seem to be somewhat oscillatory, but not very nicely.

I also apologize for not providing some code to generate similar looking data. I would, if I had an idea of how to go about that, but I don't as I'm not sure what kind of function would generate this type of trend.

Instead I have uploaded the x-coordinates (Frequency in GHz) and the y-coordinates (complex reflection coefficient) [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dd6spic783d98wl/CQData.dat?dl=0) (Dropbox, should be safe and registration free to download it). I should definitely add that what is plotted above is the absolute value of the y-coordinates.

Note that it doesn't require registration. It'll pop up a registration dialog when you open the site, but you can close this, and then you can click the download button (although it seems greyed out, but it isn't). They write this here too dropbox.com/help/20

Comment: Does the theory give any idea on what the nonlinear trend might be?

Comment: Ah, good point. This is one dataset of many, taken with a Vector Network Analyser. It's connected to the device with SMP cables, which are calibrated before doing the measurement. The calibration is supposed to take care of these trends, but in this case it didn't. So, does theory tell us something.. I'm not sure. I think the noise comes from the cables, and that it might have some oscillatory component to it, but beyond that I can't say. The reason I don't just remeasure is that it is done at liquid helium temperatures, so I'd rather post process.

Comment: Is the broad peak on the underlying signal symmetrical if plotted on a log scale on the x-axis, might it be a very wide resonance peak? Otherwise it looks like it might have a component which could be modelled as a piecewise linear function. Without data it's a little hard to say.

Comment: I believe you should post _at least:_ one dataset, or go asking  [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/) instead

Comment: Okay, let me think of a way to post the data. Is uploading it to some file sharing website okay?

Comment: @user129412 As long as it is "clean" (Free, no passwords, no registration and standard download methods), yes

Comment: Alright, I edited the main post with a link to the file. It's on my dropbox, but it should work without having to log in or anything as far as I know

Comment: @image_doctor I'm having some trouble getting it to show a log scale on the x-axis, mathematica that is. I'm using ListLogPlot but it just shows the normal scales. The resonances themselves should be symmetric, but I don't think that is what you mean.

Comment: @user129412 What do you make of the output of `ListLogLogPlot[MeanFilter[Abs@dat[[All, 2]], 7000]]`

Comment: @image_doctor Interesting. I'm not too experienced with looking at log-log plots. In that plane it has the shape of a Gaussian. In just the normal ListPlot, it seems like a sine to me.

Comment: Take a look at `ListPlot@Im[ToExpression@data[[All, 2]]]`. The imaginary component seems to have a phase shift when "traversing" a resonance. Perhaps you need to take that on account first.

Comment: @belisarius Thanks for pointing that out, but this is actually expected from theory. The argument and the absolute value are complementary in that sense; they both show resonances, but in a rather different way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than modelling the non-linearity analytically, I've directly attempted to remove it. The longer trend features of the spectrum have been extracted by smoothing out most of the noise and signal, then subtracting these from the original spectrum.

A convenient way to do this is with an interpolation function, `Interpolation`, constructed from the smoothed spectrum.

```
freqs = dat[[All, 1]];
vals =  Abs@dat[[All, 2]];
smoothedVals = MeanFilter[vals, 5000];
if = Interpolation[{freqs, smoothedVals}\[Transpose]];
trdat = {First@#, Last@# - if@First@#} & /@ ({freqs, vals}\[Transpose]);
```

I've chosen a value of 5000 to samples to smooth the spectrum with as this gives what looks like to me the 'nicest' non-linearity. (3000 samples produces a nicer spectrum, but the non-linearity looks less attractive, try the values for yourself ). Below is a plot of the interpolation function for a 5000 sample window:

```
ListPlot[{First@#, if@First@#} & /@ ({freqs, vals}\[Transpose]), AxesLabel -> {"Freq", "Amplitude"};
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Subtracting the non-linearity from the spectrum gives us this the spectrum with the non-linearity removed:

```
ListPlot[trdat, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"Freq", "Amplitude"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can get a version of the spectrum with noise more centred on zero by reducing the number of samples to smooth by, but the non-linearity looks more disjointed and it disturbs the level of the response peaks.

If you drop the smoothing window size down to 100 samples you begin to see the level shift associated with too small a sample window and more noise, and the signal, appearing in the non-linearity:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Further low pass filtering of the spectrum shows what maybe some harmonic interaction:

```
ListPlot[{freqs, MeanFilter[trdat[[All, 2]], 50]}\[Transpose],
```

PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"Freq", "Amplitude"}]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It may be worth noting that noise amplitude seems to increase with frequency, so it may not be Gaussian.

Comment: Hm, I think this might be a manual version of a highpass filter in the end, right? It certainly also does work, and it is a little more transparent (if you don't know digital filters all that well, like me)

Comment: Broadly yes, it's the  subtraction of a low pass filtered signal which isolates the observed non-linearity. Maybe that will give you some insight into it's origin ?

Comment: Well, I'm very new to experimental physics (my first project really), so I'm not too familiar with all the complications yet. I'm sure it'll make a nice discussion with my supervisor. If I would guess, it is something with reflections in the cables.

Comment: I'm not sure which approach is better, in terms of the results. They both seem good to me. However, I didn't come up with the answer I posted below, someone else did, so I'll accept yours as it is a nice alternative.

Comment: I'm actually having trouble with the result from below. The peak height seems to be strongly changed, which is a problem. I'll have to re-examine it, see if it is fixable, and if not if your approach provides a better solution.

Answer (score 5):

Credit goes to Ondřej Grover from the Signal Processing stackexchange. He suggested using a High pass filter, as it clearly seems to be some low frequency signal. His solution involved a Python script (found [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24104/removing-a-non-linear-noise-trend-from-data)) but something similar can be done with Mathematica.

Using a forward-backward method and some experimentation with cutoff values, we can use Mathematica's `Highpassfilter` to fix our data (which I originally defined as `Sxx`:

```
Sxxfiltered = 
  HighpassFilter[HighpassFilter[Abs[Sxx], 0.0003], 0.0003];
```

If we now look at what the data looks like, we see that instead of the curvey data we had before, we instead get a nice, straight line.
[image]

As you can see on the y-axis the scale is no longer as before, but this can be corrected for without too much trouble.