# Discrete Fourier Transform baseline subtraction

Tags: fourier-analysis, time-series

I am trying to remove sinusoidal variability from a set of evenly-spaced intensity vs. time data. These data contain periodic events that are separated by a normalized (but sinusoidally variable) baseline. Essentially I need to remove the variability from my ENTIRE data set based on the variability I find in my baseline. How would I go about doing this?

I realize this is likely a duplicate question but I have not found anything that helps me yet. Thanks!

Comment: This may help http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85845/removing-a-non-linear-noise-trend-from-data/85870#85870

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: How about a `BandstopFilter` with the band right near the frequency of the undesirable sinusoid?

Comment: I should have mentioned this before, the variability is due to a linear combination of sine waves at all different frequencies, and I do not know beforehand how many independent frequencies exist.

Comment: If you can share a sample of your data, you may get better responses :)